# PHP - Creating OAuth Authorization Header

Tags: php, curl, oauth, authorization, quickbooks

I'm trying to integrate the QuickBooks Online API and need to create the Authorization header for my request. I know they have an SDK and other tools out there, but they look like they're for using XML. Or at least that's how I perceived them. I just want to make requests using their REST API and send/receive JSON. I figure I'll use cURL.

I'm stuck at the part where I need to create the Authorization header. I think I have all the components I need, but I can't figure out how to properly generate the `oauth_signature` using PHP.

I'm not sure why this seems so difficult to figure out, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm able to perform the request using Chrome's Postman, and it works there. If I have Postman generate the cURL code for me, and use it in my app, that works as well. What I'm seeing is that the `oauth_signature` value I generate is not correct. But I'm following the guidelines over at http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process as close as possible.

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you're actually doing? It's standard OAuth...

Comment: I figured it out. The part I was missing was sorting the parameters by name, even though I already knew about that. Sometimes it's just the simple things.